# SQL Double Select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my Table

```
sno | city | state | stateid

1   | chennai | tamilnadu | 1

2   | dindigul | tamilnadu | 1

3   | trivandrum | Kerala | 2

4   | cochin | Kerala | 2
```

I want to display like this (State Id should be selected on ascending, and the city should be displayed still it reaches the greater stateid )

**tamilnadu**

chennai

dindigul

**Kerala**

trivandrum

cochin

How can i achieve this ?

What i have tried so far is

```
(select city from (select * from state order by statid asc))
```

There the inner query is running (select * from state order by stateid asc), but while i use the `(select city from (innerquery)`.

It is throwing `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in PHP:

```
 <?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbname");

$rs = $con->query('select city, state from mytable');
while ($row = $rs->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $state_cities[$row['state']][] = $row['city'];
}

foreach ($state_cities as $state => $cities) {
  echo "<b>".$state . "</b><br>";
  foreach ($cities as $title) {
  echo $title . "<br>";
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: But in the while declaring $rs it is showing 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\state.php on line 4

Comment: @JaiKrish, sorry forgot to include the connection. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(select city from (select * from state order by statid asc))
```

It needs the table name Where and field name with an operator.

```
(select city from <TableName> WHERE <FieldName> <Operator> (select * from state order by statid asc))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a proper normalized table as state_name and id are getting redundant. If there is a possibility of editing the table structure you can break the tables as following:

```
cities:

sno city_name state_id
1 chennai 1
2 dindigul  1
3 trivandrum 2
4 cochin 2

states:

state_id state_name
1 tamilnadu
2 kerala
```

Then you can use query like :

```
SELECT c.city_name,s.state_name FROM cities c INNER JOIN states s ON c.state_id = s.`state_id` ORDER BY c.state_id ASC;
```

**SQL DUMP:**

```
/*
SQLyog Ultimate v10.00 Beta1
MySQL - 5.5.24-log : Database - test
*********************************************************************
*/


/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=''*/;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`test` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `test`;

/*Table structure for table `cities` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cities`;

CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sno`,`state_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `cities` */

insert  into `cities`(`sno`,`city_name`,`state_id`) values (1,'chennai',1),(2,'dingi',1),(3,'cochin',2),(4,'efef',2);

/*Table structure for table `states` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `states`;

CREATE TABLE `states` (
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`state_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `states` */

insert  into `states`(`state_id`,`state_name`) values (1,'tamilnadu'),(2,'kerala');

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```